# mongodb: converting object ID's to BSON::ObjectId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

We have recently upgraded our application to Rails3 and we are now using Mongoid, and we have a problem retrieving previous documents from mongo-db by `_id`.

Upon closer investigation, an old record (which I can't retrieve by `_id`) look as follows:

```
#<Audit::Log _id: 4d892bfe6bcaff4ffd000001, 
    failed: nil, request_id: "68ccb38e9e345bb7fc55331389a902a1", 
    session_id: "54940ff7e8c7336d813a872db7cb7bc0", 
    _id: "4d892bfe6bcaff4ffd000001", ... }>
```

and a good record has the following structure:

```
#<Audit::Log _id: 4d892bfe6bcaff4ffd000001, 
    failed: nil, request_id: "68ccb38e9e345bb7fc55331389a902a1", 
    session_id: "54940ff7e8c7336d813a872db7cb7bc0", 
    _id: BSON::ObjectId('4d892bfe6bcaff4ffd000001'), ... }>
```

As you can see, the `_id` field is different. For the old records it seems to be just a string, and for the new records it is a `BSON::ObjectID`.

I can't seem to be able to retrieve the records with the old format. Trying to find the records using

```
Audit::Log.where(:_id => BSON::ObjectId('4d892bfe6bcaff4ffd000001')).first
Audit::Log.where(:_id => '4d892bfe6bcaff4ffd000001').first
```

both return `nil`.

But for the good record, I can just do

```
Audit::Log.where(:'_id' => '4e14152d6bcaff26bb000039').first
```

I am guessing, but maybe Mongoid automatically converts the string to an `ObjectId` to find on `_id`? The only fix I see would be to convert 
all the `_id`-fields to `BSON::ObjectId` if they are not already. But how do I do that?

Or do you have a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, I should have looked further at the Mongoid documentation. They have a section describing [how to upgrade](http://mongoid.org/docs/upgrading.html). In the section to upgrade to 2.0.0.BETA.11 + they describe that the `_id`'s now no longer are `String` and they point to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/489098) to convert all your ids from `string` to `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 7):

All of these will work, provided the record actually exists:

```
Account.where(:_id => "4e0a9c6142f5bc769f000008").first
Account.find(BSON::ObjectId("4e0a9c6142f5bc769f000008"))
Account.find("4e0a9c6142f5bc769f000008")
```

I'm interested in the JSON returned about a Audit::Log... Why are there two _id fields returned?

```
#<Audit::Log _id: 4d892bfe6bcaff4ffd000001, 
    failed: nil, request_id: "68ccb38e9e345bb7fc55331389a902a1", 
    session_id: "54940ff7e8c7336d813a872db7cb7bc0", 
    _id: "4d892bfe6bcaff4ffd000001", ... }>
```

You may want to drop to the mongo driver and see if this log truly exists in the database. Unless you are declaring another "_id" field in the audit_log.rb, I believe this record does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Ex: Here is an id
    1.9.3-p125 :096 >   profile_id
    => “4fe969dd79216d0af9000002″
    1.9.3-p125 :099 >   BSON::ObjectId.from_string(profile_id)
    => BSON::ObjectId(’4fe969dd79216d0af9000002′)