# Can't convert BSON::ObjectId into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

So........   I have a rails app.  The rails app uses Mongoid for mongodb data.  When I create mongo records through web forms, they have IDs with type `string`.  When I import records into mongo using mongoimport, they have IDs with type `BSON::ObjectId`.

The rails app is expecting the mongo record IDs to be strings, and therefore when I import the data, it causes my app to fail because when it looks up the records it complains that it `can't convert type BSON::ObjectId to string`

I'm confused on a number of levels here.  BSON::ObjectId is the default type for IDs in mongo, so I don't understand why the records created through rails and Mongoid have string IDs.  I don't see anywhere where Mongoid is specifying that the _id field should be a string.  Does anybody have any clues?

Comment: what version of mongoid are you using?

Comment: So I figured it out.  The issue is with the version of Mongoid that is used by my application.  Version 1.9.5 uses strings as the default type for the _id field, which is what I'm using.  Ultimately, I'll have to build a rake task to import the records, so I can use Mongoid 1.9.5 to create them.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

What version of Mongoid are you using?  From this post, it looks like Mongoid was using strings up until a year ago for _id's but now consistently uses  the BSON::ObjectId type.

[mongodb: converting object ID's to BSON::ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596814/mongodb-converting-object-ids-to-bsonobjectid)

It references this gist for converting old documents with String _id's to using BSON::ObjectId type _id's.

When Mongoid inserts a document into a collection, it expects and uses the BSON::ObjectId type.  This is an example using the Rails console:

> post = Post.new
>    => # 
>   post.save
>    => true 
>   post._id
>    => BSON::ObjectId('4ff5bcb39ef1728393000002') 
>   post._id.class
>    => BSON::ObjectId

Mongoid appears to know to look up _id's using the BSON::ObjectId type:

> Post.where(:_id => "4ff5bcb39ef1728393000002").count
>    => 1
>
> Post.where(:_id => BSON::ObjectId("4ff5bcb39ef1728393000002") ).count
>    => 1

Are you, by any chance, manually setting the _id's?  If you are, then perhaps you're not setting the _id's as BSON::ObjectId types.

Comment: You're right.  The issue is with the version of mongoid i'm using.  Rather than try to convert the existing mongo documents and updating mongoid, I wrote a rake task to import the data within my app environment.  I posted it below.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

About your last paragraph: MongoDB's [specification](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) is expecting for 12 byte string.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.  The issue is with the version of Mongoid that is used by my application.  Version 1.9.5 uses strings as the default type for the _id field, which is what I'm using.

I thought about updating Mongoid, but I was afraid that the old string IDs would somehow break the application.

The answer was to somehow import the records using the rails app, so that the old version of Mongoid would be in charge of inserting the records.  I created a rake task that would parse the CSV file and insert the records from that file within my app environment.

```
require 'csv'
require 'iconv'
namespace :deadline do
  desc "Import data from CSV file"
  task :import => :environment do
    CSV.parse(File.open("/tmp/deadlines.csv").read).map{ |row|
      app_deadline = OrgSpecific::ApplicationDeadline.create!(
        :name => row[2] + " " + row[3],
        :start_date => Date.strptime('1/1/2012', '%m/%d/%Y'),
        :deadline_date => Date.strptime(row[11], '%m/%d/%Y'),
        :term => row[2],
        :year => row[3],
        :comment => Iconv.conv("UTF8", "LATIN1", row[5]) + " : " + Iconv.conv("UTF8", "LATIN1", row[6])
      )
    }
  end
end
```

And voila!  All the data from my CSV file has been imported through my rails environment, meaning that my mongo records have an _id of type string.  Thanks for the help guys!